# insert a jquery table with scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to insert two tables in the same div in a row with a button but they appear one over the other, and i would put a scroll, someone can help me? thank you.

Here's my code

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <button class="stile.query" onclick="loadContatori(1, 'nome', 'asc');">Click me</button>
    <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="325">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300" >
                    <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
                        <th id="nome">Punto di interesse</th>
                        <th id="n_poi">Numero</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width:320px; height:60px; overflow:auto;">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="300" >
                        <tr>
                            <td id="nome"></td>
                            <td id="n_poi"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you upload an image the way you want

Comment: Not really sure what you want - try adding `style='float:left'` or `style='display:inline'` to the button and outer table.

Comment: when i click the button the tables have to be in the same div at the same height, for example this table i'll upload repeated 


CodeIgniter-MySQL-Bootstrap-read-display-table.png